# getState in redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a store with a list of items. When my app first loads, I need to deserialize the items, as in create some in-memory objects based on the items. The items are stored in my redux store and handled by an `itemsReducer`.

I'm trying to use [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) to handle the deserialization, as a side effect. On first page load, I dispatch an action:

```
dispatch( deserializeItems() );
```

My saga is set up simply:

```
function* deserialize( action ) {
    // How to getState here??
    yield put({ type: 'DESERISLIZE_COMPLETE' });
}

function* mySaga() {
    yield* takeEvery( 'DESERIALIZE', deserialize );
}
```

In my deserialize saga, where I want to handle the side effect of creating in-memory versions of my items, I need to read the existing data from the store. I'm not sure how to do that here, or if that's a pattern I should even be attempting with redux-saga.

Comment: why do you want to read the data from the store ? can't you just pass the data in the action payload ?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

you can use **[select effect](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#selectselector-args)**

```
import {select, ...} from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* deserialize( action ) {
    const state = yield select();
    ....
    yield put({ type: 'DESERIALIZE_COMPLETE' });
}
```

also you can use it with selectors

```
const getItems = state => state.items;

function* deserialize( action ) {
    const items = yield select(getItems);
    ....
    yield put({ type: 'DESERIALIZE_COMPLETE' });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from [@Kokovin Vladislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5438212/kokovin-vladislav), if we like to use typing of **Typescript**, we could use **"defined typed hooks"** pattern introduced by **redux-toolkit** on this doc: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks.

So, in the `app/hooks.ts` file we have:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

import { select } from 'redux-saga/effects'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector` ( From redux-toolkit docs )
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

// THIS IS THE ADDITIONAL SELECTOR!!!!!!!
export function* appSelect<TSelected>( selector: (state: RootState) => TSelected, ): Generator<any, TSelected, TSelected> { return yield select(selector); }
```

Then in your generator function, you could do similar like this:

```
import { appSelect } from "app/hooks"

function* deserialize( action ) {
    const items = yield* appSelect(state => state.items);
    ....
    yield put({ type: 'DESERIALIZE_COMPLETE' });
}
```

That way we have strong typing and intelisense of `state` on each call of `appSelect()`.

Credit: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/970#issuecomment-880799390

Answer (score -7):

Select effect does not help us if we in a callback functions, when code flow is not handled by Saga. In this case just pass `dispatch` and `getState` to root saga:

```
store.runSaga(rootSaga, store.dispatch, store.getState)
```

And the pass parameters to child sagas

`export default function* root(dispatch, getState) {
  yield all([
    fork(loginFlow, dispatch, getState),
  ])
}`

And then in watch methods

`export default function* watchSomething(dispatch, getState)
...`

Comment: This seems more like an anti-pattern. Redux saga is middleware already and shouldn't need something this kludgy. What is a callback function not handled by a saga? How does passing something INTO the saga help something that is not handled by the saga?

Comment: I do not agree. `yield select()` is only applicable at saga context. Only. Saga can involve some functions, other libraries with user interactions via callbacks. By that time when callback fired  - saga may not present at all. This is a way how to use Store, when Saga is out. (for example frontend microservices, web-component approach with multiple stores, saga, react and so on)