# Redux Saga select is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to get my state from inside a saga using the `select` effect.

I used this answer to start - [getState in redux-saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405700/getstate-in-redux-saga)

Code:

```
const { select } = ReduxSaga
select()
```

[Using this codepen redux saga setup (line 35).](http://codepen.io/rkhayat/pen/273d838271d2bf1d3c091f759e3b1be3/?editors=0010)

**`Error - select is not a function`**

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` is `undefined`.

You may need to upgrade your version of `react-saga` from `0.5.0` to a higher version.

e.g. From https://npmcdn.com/redux-saga@**0.5.0**/dist/redux-saga.min.js to https://npmcdn.com/redux-saga@**0.9.0**/dist/redux-saga.min.js

(At least 0.9.0 is ok in my test. 0.12.1 is the latest.)

And import it from `ReduxSaga.effects`

```
const { put, call, select } = ReduxSaga.effects;
```

**The revised will be:**

[image]

Comment: Do'h!! Thanks! It's getting there! `select first argument must be a function`, There must be a way to return the whole state without a selector?

Comment: From Docs `If select is called without argument (i.e. yield select()) then the effect is resolved with the entire state (the same result of a getState() call).`

Comment: Thanks! This worked...
`const getState = state => state`
 `var state = yield select(getState)`

Comment: Yep, 0.9.0 doesn't allow `selector` can be `null`. 0.12.1 allows it. The Docs you read should be the latest, right? Congrats that you get it worked.